# Overparameterization at the final layer of a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, softmax

I'm considering a multi-class classifying neural network with softmax on the final layer. Should one of the classes of the weight matrix of the final layer not be optimised over to account for the fact that the probabilities have to sum to one? I don't see any mention of this in the textbooks I've been reading on neural networks (e.g. Andreas Lindholm et al's [Machine Learning - A First Course for Engineers and Scientists](http://smlbook.org)). Is it not so much of a problem if you're using SGD rather than a quasi-Newton method?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct: softmax eliminates one degree of freedom (since the sum is constrained to 1).
In practice, it does not hurt optimization: this is the common formulation for multinomial GLMs as well.

One way around it, however, is using Stick-Breaking Processes.
These are commonplace in the formulation of Dirichlet Processes, but, in a multinomial/categorical regression setting consists of modelling $k$ probabilities $p_i$ with $k-1$ outputs $0 \leq o_i \leq 1$, with the following constraint:

\begin{cases}
p_0=o_0\\
p_1=(1-p_0)\cdot o_1\\
p_2=(1-p_1)\cdot o_2=(1-(1-p_0)\cdot o_1)\cdot o_2\\
p_i=(1 - p_{i-1}) \cdot o_i\\
p_k=(1 - p_{k-1})
\end{cases}

Intuitively, it consists of modeling each probability from the remainder of the last one, e.g., $(1-p_0)$ is the probability that the output is not $0$.

Comment: But in GLMs I know it’s common to  set the coefficients of the weight matrix belonging to one class to zero because of this constraint. I wanted to know if this is commonly done in neural networks?

Comment: @oweydd "But in GLMs I know it’s common to set the coefficients of the weight matrix belonging to one class to zero because of this constraint." I don't understand what you mean by this, could you expand?